# Richfaces: how to render ids based on event.rf.data returned after an event dataavailable?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am working on some Java JSF and Richfaces 4 application, I'm new to all those technos, including Java, so everything you can tell me, even basics, could help me :) .

I have

1. an a4j:commandButton triggering a bean method through its actionListener attribute
2. This bean method publishes a list of ids on a topic called "updateGUI"
3. Back in the view file, there is an a4j:push, that listens to this "updateGUI" topic, with a child node a4j:ajax, with event "dataavailable"

These 3 points work. My only problem here is that I want the a4j:ajax to render ids contained in the javascript event.rf.data , but I didn't succeed in doing so. If I write ids by hand, instead of using the event.rf.data, they get rendered.

here is the xhtml :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" template="/templates/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="title">RichFaces Sample</ui:define>
  <ui:define name="body">
    <a4j:push address="updateGUI">
      <!-- here, instead of render="main butt0" (the added button and the parent node),
           I'd like to use event.rf.data, a javascript variable containing the ids
           I don't want to call a bean's getter, since the bean could have created/
           updated/deleted other ids, and we could miss old updated ids, and also
           getters are called multiple times (so can't make a FIFO of updated ids) -->
      <a4j:ajax event="dataavailable" limitRender="true" render="main butt0" />
    </a4j:push>
    <h:form id="main">
      <h:inputText value="#{pushtest.text}">
    <a4j:ajax event="change" />
      </h:inputText>
      <a4j:commandButton value="create a new button!" actionListener="#{pushtest.makemodifthread}" />
      <a4j:outputPanel id="status">
        last updated ids: #{pushtest.logupdated_ids}
      </a4j:outputPanel>
      <br />
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and its templates/template.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<h:head>
    <title>RichFaces Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </h:head>

<h:body>
        <ui:insert name="body">Default content</ui:insert>
</h:body>
</html>
```

here is the bean :

```
package unit1;

import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.lang.Runnable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.richfaces.application.push.MessageException;
import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicKey;
import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicsContext;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.richfaces.component.UICommandButton;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class pushtest {
    // from http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html
    private UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent c, String id) {
    if (id.equals(c.getId())) {
    return c;
    }
    java.util.Iterator<UIComponent> kids = c.getFacetsAndChildren();
    while (kids.hasNext()) {
    UIComponent found = findComponent(kids.next(), id);
    if (found != null) {
        return found;
    }
    }
    return null;
    }

    public void makemodifthread(ActionEvent event) throws MessageException
    {
    UICommandButton butt = new UICommandButton();
    updated_ids = "butt"+ count;
    butt.setId("butt" + count);
    count++;
    butt.setValue(this.text);
    UIComponent parent = findComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot(), "main");
    parent.getChildren().add(butt);
    updated_ids += " " + parent.getId();
        TopicKey topicKey = new TopicKey("updateGUI");
        TopicsContext topicsContext = TopicsContext.lookup();
        topicsContext.publish(topicKey, updated_ids);
    }

    public String getLogupdated_ids()
    {
    System.out.println("LOG updated ids: " + log_updated_ids);
    return (log_updated_ids);
    }

    public String getUpdated_ids()
    {
    System.out.println("updated ids: " + updated_ids);
    if (!updated_ids.isEmpty())
    {
        log_updated_ids = updated_ids;
        updated_ids = "";
        return (log_updated_ids);
    }
    return (updated_ids);
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
    this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
    return (text);  
    }

    private String text = "button name";
    private String updated_ids = "";
    private String log_updated_ids = "";
    private int count = 0;
}
```

Bye

Comment: please share with what you've already done

Comment: Sorry to tell you mate, you will not get a proper answer without showing what you have done so far.

Comment: @shevchik: added the sources :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved this problem in a more simple way, thanks to this : http://www.coderanch.com/t/562602/JSF/java/assign-JSF-Ajax-Render-attribute#post_text_2554972

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(target.getClientId());
```

In the bean, I can now add/update jsf nodes, without having to worries about websockets, id getters or other weird stuff.

edit : actually, this solution is not perfect, I needed to combine it with an a4j:push. More info next week!